# Execute php code stored in database

Tags: php, dynamic, content-management-system, echo

```
<div class="division2">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-12">
               <p style="text-align: justify">
                      <?php echo $content->content ?>
               </p>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Im trying to build a custom CMS for a project. This block of code is stored in database but the problem is that the php code cannot execute its functionality like echo.

I tried to use `{{ $content->content }}` but the browser reads it as a string.
Through my research I encountered `eval()` but cannot make it to work and they said that it's too risky.

Answer (score 0):

You have to end it with `;` in `<?php echo $content->content ?>` first as `<?php echo $content->content; ?>` So, you can use `printf` as `<?php echo printf('%s',$content->content); ?>`

So, if you are using objects, maybe you have to write the function that you have into your class that you were instanced before. So, the output had to be:

```
<?php echo printf('%s', $content->content() ); ?>
```

Please see that we have to end `->content()` as a function that exists inside your class.

Comment: It only shows content() ); ?>  as output. When I looked in the page source the line is colored red before content() ); ?> .